# Is there any way to share resources in a Silverlight library project?

Tags: silverlight, resources

In a silverlight application you have App.xaml, but in a Silverlight library you don't.  I tried using generic.xaml but I think this serves the specific purpose of applying styles to all controls based on their type.  In case, I just want a place to put things like paths or objects that I will reuse throughout the library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Silverlight Toolkit's [SharedResources.cs](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/25992?projectName=Silverlight#636822) file, it's a little hacky but may help with your scenario.

It isn't the same as sharing XAML resources, but it may help you get access to images and other embedded content types.